# Draw a rectangular prism and label its dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, shapes

I'm trying to prepare a worksheet for my students on calculating the volume of a rectangular prism (cuboid). Using the code below I manage to generate the rectangular prism, but how do I add the dimensions? I'd like to have, for example, "4cm" for the length, placed just under the length line, "4cm" for the width, placed below right of the width line, and "6cm" for the height, placed to the right of the height line.

1. what is the code for doing that?
2. Generally speaking, how do I position these dimensions where I like? I may want to rotate the prism and place the dimensions above, below, center, right or left of the prism outlines. How do I do that?

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1.5}
\path (0,0,\y) coordinate (A) (\x,0,\y) coordinate (B) (\x,0,0) coordinate (C) (0,0,0)
coordinate (D) (0,\z,\y) coordinate (E) (\x,\z,\y) coordinate (F) (\x,\z,0) coordinate (G)
(0,\z,0) coordinate (H);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(G)--(F)--(B) (A)--(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(E);
\draw [black] (A)--(D)--(C) (D)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1.5}
\path (0,0,\y) coordinate (A) (\x,0,\y) coordinate (B) (\x,0,0) coordinate (C) (0,0,0)
coordinate (D) (0,\z,\y) coordinate (E) (\x,\z,\y) coordinate (F) (\x,\z,0) coordinate (G)
(0,\z,0) coordinate (H);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(G)--(F)--(B) (A)--(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(E);
\draw (A)--(D)--(C) (D)--(H);

\draw[thin,|<->|] ($(A)+(0,-4pt)$) -- node[below]{4cm}($(B)+(0,-4pt)$);
\draw[thin,|<->|] ($(B)+(-45:4pt)$) -- node[below,sloped]{4cm}($(C)+(-45:4pt)$);
\draw[thin,|<->|] ($(C)+(4pt,0)$) -- node[below,sloped]{6cm}($(G)+(4pt,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To start with, you might want to view the position of the coordinated. That can be done by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1.5}
\path (0,0,\y) coordinate (A) (\x,0,\y) coordinate (B) (\x,0,0) coordinate (C) (0,0,0)
coordinate (D) (0,\z,\y) coordinate (E) (\x,\z,\y) coordinate (F) (\x,\z,0) coordinate (G)
(0,\z,0) coordinate (H);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(G)--(F)--(B) (A)--(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(E);
\draw [black] (A)--(D)--(C) (D)--(H);
\foreach \coor in {A,B,...,H}{%
  \node[above] at (\coor){\coor};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

With that it is easier to include the text as nodes in the drawing (I also dashed the hidden lines):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1.5}
\path (0,0,\y) coordinate (A) (\x,0,\y) coordinate (B) (\x,0,0) coordinate (C) (0,0,0)
coordinate (D) (0,\z,\y) coordinate (E) (\x,\z,\y) coordinate (F) (\x,\z,0) coordinate (G)
(0,\z,0) coordinate (H);
\draw (A)-- node[below]{4cm} (B)-- node[below,sloped]{4cm} (C)--(G)--(F)--(B) (A)-- node[above,sloped]{6cm}(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(E);
\draw [dashed,black] (A)--(D)--(C) (D)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The rotation can be done by changing the coordinate system basis vectirs. Tikz plots the lines on a 2-dimensional space, but you can use 3-dimensional vectors (projected to 2-dim). (Since the coordinates in the example and tikz are using different orders of y and z, there is a slight confusion in the code below):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.2]{$x$};
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.2]{$z$};
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.2]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.7cm,-0.7cm)},y={(0.2cm,0.7cm)},z={(-0.7cm,-0.7cm)}]
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.2]{$x$};
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.2]{$z$};
\draw[->](0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.2]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

To rotate the prism one can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.7cm,-0.7cm)},y={(0.2cm,0.7cm)},z={(-0.7cm,-0.7cm)}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{1.5}
\path (0,0,\y) coordinate (A) (\x,0,\y) coordinate (B) (\x,0,0) coordinate (C) (0,0,0)
coordinate (D) (0,\z,\y) coordinate (E) (\x,\z,\y) coordinate (F) (\x,\z,0) coordinate (G)
(0,\z,0) coordinate (H);
\draw (A)-- node[below,sloped,]{4cm} (B)-- node[below,sloped]{4cm} (C)--(G)--(F)--(B) (A)-- node[above,sloped]{6cm}(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(E);
\draw [dashed,black] (A)--(D)--(C) (D)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]